# anonymous forum topics on Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

i want to allow anonymous users to create forum topics with their information ( name, email ) and also to be able to alert them when a new comment is posted. There is any simple way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and use ADVANCED FORUM module for your drupal site.It contains vast features that will help you to design efficient forum discussion.After installing the module
check whether the anonymous check box is enabled if not enable that check box to.If you have any doubt refer the documentation before installing the advanced forum module.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look to the *Anonymous Posting* module http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_posting which allow anonymous users to fill their contact informations just like for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the anonymous user role the permission to create forum posts ("create forum topics") and comment ("post comments", you probably also want "post comments without approval").

For notifications, there are several modules available, a simple one that also works well for anonymous users is http://drupal.org/project/comment_notify. Users just need to tick the checkbox when they write a comment and they will receive an alert when an answer is posted.

Comment: But drupal forum dont allow anonymous user to leave their email and name when creating TOPICS. How comment notify can alert them without an email adress ?